# Chamar variável protected dentro de método estático

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, variáveis, métodos-estáticos

```
<?php

     class Foo{

          protected $calc;

          function __construct(){
               $this->calc = 2;
          }

          public static function getCalc(){
               return $this->calc * 5;
          }
     }
     Foo::getCalc();
```

Quando rodo, ele me da esse erro:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in...

Porquê eu não posso chamar uma variável `protected` dentro de uma função definida como estática?

Comment: Porque a variável não existe no escopo estático. Entenda que as variáveis não estáticas só passam a existir quando o objeto da classe é criado, por isso o erro. Para usar a variável, VC precisa primeiro  criar um objeto Foo.

Comment: O problema não é o protected mas o fato de você manipular um atributo da instancia em um método estático, ele pertence a classe e não ao objeto, logo o acessoa ao `$this` não é válido.

Comment: Certo, e qual seria a solução disso? Mudar estatico para público?

Comment: Esse código parece ser um exemplo apenas ... não faz muito ... o objetivo do método ser estático é para economizar a criação de um objeto? pode resolver isso com um valor fixo ou uma constante.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pense em todos os membros estáticos como uma instância única pré-instanciada na aplicação, é como se estes membros pertencessem a outro objeto.

Já os membros considerados de instância pertencem cada um à sua própria instância (pode ser uma variável). Não tem como misturá-los, no fundo são coisas muito distintas em locais de memória diferentes com papeis diferentes.

Mesmo que tente, de qual `$this` estamos falando? Esta é uma variável que guarda a instância, a linguagem não sabe de qual objeto está falando no código, afinal ali está acessando algo que não é de nenhuma instância normal.

Comment: mesmo que use `self::` o atributo protected tambem teria que ser `static`?

Comment: Não é possível ser `static` e `protected` ao mesmo tempo. O fato de ser estático impede que aconteça herança, então não faz sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível acessar atributos da classe nem outros métodos dentro de um método estático. Métodos estáticos não estão no contexto do objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Essa é uma pergunta antiga, ainda assim vou responder pois pode ajudar quem visitar o post.
Estanciando a própria classe dentro da função static funciona, assim:

```
class Foo {

    protected $calc;

    function __construct(){
        $this->calc = 2;
    }

    public static function getCalc() {
        $foo = new Foo();
        return $foo->calc * 5;
    }
}
     echo Foo::getCalc();
```